# Laravel integration test: how to assert an URL has been called but another URL no

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, integration-testing

I would like to test a controller that makes a request to an certain URL (EG: `http://example.com/api/say-hello`) but it does not make a request to another URL (EG: `http://example.com/api/say-bye-bye`).

The controller function I want to test looks like this:

```php
public function callApis(Request $request)
{
    $data = $this->validate($request, [
        'say_bye_bye' => 'nullable|boolean',
    ]);

    Http::get('http://example.com/api/say-hello');

    if ($data['say_bye_bye']) {
        Http::get('http://example.com/api/say-bye-bye');
    }
}
```

In my integration tests, I want to make sure that:

- If the parameter `say_bye_bye` is `TRUE` then both of the API endpoints `/api/say-hello` and `/api/say-bye-bye` must be called.
- If the parameter `say_bye_bye` is `FALSE` then just the API `/api/say-hello` has to be called and the API endpoint `/api/say-bye-bye` must NOT be called.

---

So far I managed to verify if one or two calls have been made using `Http::assertSentCount(int $count)`.
The solution can be getting the sequence of URLs called by the controller I'm testing, but it seems like there is no way.

Comment: did the recent activity reveal a solution for this of your questions as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Http::spy()

```
    Http::spy()
        ->expects('get')
        ->with('http://example.com/api/say-hello')
        ->once();
    Http::spy()
        ->expects('get')
        ->with('http://example.com/api/say-bye-bye')
        ->never();
```

Comment: Yes, I've already read it. The documentation does not say (or I didn't understand) how to test if 2 or more external requests have been made in the same controller function I want to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer but this does not help me. The `Http::fake([ ... ])` it just fakes the response. I don't care about the response. I wish to assert that a request to `api/say-hello` has been done and a request `api/say-bye-bye` has not been done.
I tried to user `Http::assertSent` and `Http::assertNotSent` but it intercepts just one response, so in case of `say_bye_bye` == `TRUE` the test fails.

Comment: Thanks again, 
I tried your solution anyway, but I get the error on the second `Http::spy()` whether I make one call or 2: `Error: Call to a member function expects() on null`.
As I said before I tried `Http::assertSent` and `Http::assertNotSent` but I did in the wrong way. Then I got this answer that worked: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-assert-an-url-has-been-called-but-another-url-no

Comment: I didn't know about `Http::spy()` and it helped me out with others issues I had on testing command line... thanks again for your help!